# How to run a PHP application in a subfolder of a website using mod_mono on Apache?

Tags: php, debian, proxy, apache-2.4, mono

I have a website running on mono (on Debian stretch). I would like to have some subfolders which would be handled by php5 module (webmail, stats and PhpMyAdmin for example).

Is there a simple way to do that with Apache configuration or should I look into phalanger or some other solution (proxy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is configure the php5 handler as you would normally for your webserver. That could be as easy as

```
a2enmod php5
```

but I can't confirm that for Debian as I only have Ubuntu to hand.

Comment: Thanks, I added a new <Location> tag with content SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
and it is working.

Comment: Actually my first solution was not good enough since css files were being sent as text/html which caused chrome to not evaluate them correctly - error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html" .

I solved this by using
    SetHandler None
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php